# creating subscripts inside scale_x_discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 b=c("x1","x2","y1","y2","w1","w2"), 
                 c=runif(6), 
                 d=c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
p <- ggplot(aes(x=b, y=c), data=df) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~d, scales="free_x")
```

I'd like to use `expression` (or any other function) in order to create subscripts for each label. I tried this:

```
new_labels <- c(expression("x[1]"),expression("x[2]"),expression("y[1]"),expression("y[2]"),expression("w[1]"),expression("w[2]"))
p + scale_x_discrete(labels=new_labels)
```

and this

```
new_labels2 <- c("x[1]","x[2]","y[1]","y[2]","w[1]","w[2]")
p + scale_x_discrete(labels=function(new_labels2) expression(new_labels2))
```

but none of these solutions gave me the intended result.

Also how can I change the bar colors to be the same in all facets?

I thought `p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","red"))` would work, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` to generate the expressions as strings and then parse the strings to have them interpreted as expressions. In the example below I've also added `fill=grepl("1", b)` which will map column `b` to the `fill` aesthetic based on whether there's a `1` or not in the value of `b`. This mapping is necessary to generate fill colours that can then be set with `scale_fill_manual`.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x=b, y=c, fill=grepl("1", b)), data=df) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~d, scales="free_x") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=function(l) parse(text=gsub("(.)([0-9])", "\\1[\\2]", l)))

p
```

[image]

For illustration, below is what the `gsub` function is doing to generate the strings before they're parsed as expressions (basically just doing programmatically what you hard-coded in your question):

```
p <- ggplot(aes(x=b, y=c, fill=grepl("1", b)), data=df) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  facet_grid(~d, scales="free_x") +
  guides(fill=FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=function(l) gsub("(.)([0-9])", "\\1[\\2]", l))

p
```

[image]

The `gsub` function uses regular expressions to do the substitutions. If you're not familiar with regular expressions, another, perhaps less opaque way to code this would be:

```
function(l) paste0(substr(l,1,1), "[", substr(l,2,2), "]")
```

If you want to set your own fill colours, you could do:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","red"))
```

In reference to the question in your comment: You can create a dummy grouping variable as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

p <- df %>% 
  group_by(b.grp = substr(b, 1, 1)) %>% 
  mutate(grp.val = 1:n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=b, y=c, fill=factor(grp.val))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    facet_grid(~d, scales="free_x") +
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels=function(l) parse(text=gsub("(.)(.)", "\\1[\\2]", l)))
```

Comment: Thanks @eipi10 it works great! One more thing, what if my labels are `x[a], x[b], y[c], y[a], w[d], w[c]`, which is how my data set looks like? The `grepl("1",b)` trick won't work because the subscripts can be different for `x`, `y` and `w`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This is the kind of answers, well explained and detailed, that makes od SO a great place to learn. Thanks!